# ACT Math Problem for Practice

Tags: linear-algebra

If $\frac{3x-y}{x+y} = \frac{2}{5}$, then $\frac{x}{y}$?

I'm stuck. I've done analogous questions, but I can't remember how to do it. I cross multiplied, and added and subtracted variables to and from both sides, but I can't do it.

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{3x-y}{x+y}=\frac{2}{5}\quad\iff\quad 5(3x-y)=2(x+y)\quad\iff\quad 13x=7y\quad\iff \quad\frac{x}{y}=\ldots ? $$

Answer (score 0):

$\frac{3x-y}{x+y} = \frac 25$

Cross multiply:

$5(3x-y) = 2(x+y)$

Distribute, rearrange:

$15x - 5y = 2x + 2y$

$13x = 7y$

$\frac{x}{y} = \frac{7}{13}$

Comment: damn it I'm an idiot. At least my real name's not Paul.

Comment: Haha, don't be so hard on yourself, "Paul". :)